# Right Hand Sum of Function

Tags: integration, summation

I have to calculate the Right Hand Sum of an integral.

> $$f(x)=\frac x2 \ \ [1,4]$$

I am wondering if the procedure is done right. First process I will do is rewrite the problem into an integral: \begin{equation}\int_1^4 f(x)\ dx=\int_1^4 \frac x2 \ \ dx \end{equation}
The integral evaluates to the following $\frac{15}{4}$ Knowing that the right answer is that I proceeded to calculated the right hand sum.

> \begin{align}\triangle x&=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{4-1}{n}=\frac 3n\\ x^*&=a+k\triangle x=1+\frac{3}{n}k \end{align}

From here I proceeded to the following:

> \begin{align}\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x^*)\triangle x \\ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(1+\frac{3k}{n})}{2} \frac{3}n \end{align}

At the end of this I get the answer being $\frac{15}4$. Is the procedure right? I just find it weird my answer is really close to me regularly integrating it I thought there would be some error in it?

Comment: Are you asking for verifying that this sum indeed equals $\frac{15}{4}$? Or something else?

Comment: @Shamim Yes like if what I did was right too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1+\frac{3k}{n}}{2}\frac{3}{n}=\frac{3}{2n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}1+\frac{3}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k)=\frac{3}{2n}(n+\frac{3}{n}(1+..+n))=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{9}{2n^{2}}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{9}{4}+\frac{9}{4n}=\frac{15}{4}+\frac{9}{4n}$
and taking the limit we obtain the required result.

This is to be expected since for the limiting value, if it exists, the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is defined as the definite Riemann integral of the function over the domain,

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{||\Delta x||\rightarrow0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i}*)\Delta x_{i}.$$

Indeed we have $\int_{1}^{4}\frac{x}{2}dx=\frac{15}{4}$ as expected, and the left hand sum $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1+\frac{3k}{n}}{2}\frac{3}{n}$ also converges to the same value. (For a one-dimensional Riemann sum over domain $[a,b]$, as the maximum size of a partition element shrinks to zero (that is the limit of the norm of the partition goes to zero), some functions will have all Riemann sums converge to the same value)